# Batch file enter folder name or grab network id?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm attempting to build a batch file that will Delete a file from the desktop, then copy from a network location to the desktop. The idea is that this will auto update  the front end version of a database I built.

The issue I've run into is that the filepath is our network id and so I'd like to find a way that it will either recognize and use it automatically OR someone can enter it so it would use the proper path.

The code I have currently is

```
echo on

del "C:\Users\<NetworkID>\OneDrive\Desktop\CID FE v1.6" /f
xcopy "\\server\data\NFInventory\groups\CID\CID Database\CID FE v1.7 DO NOT USE -- FOR COPY ONLY.accdb" "C:\Users\<NetworkID>\OneDrive\Desktop\" /y /f
RENAME "C:\Users\<NetworkID>\OneDrive\Desktop\CID FE v1.7 DO NOT USE -- FOR COPY ONLY.accdb" CID FE v1.7.accdb

echo off
```

Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: May the network Id be the same as `%username%`?

Comment: `C:\Users\<NetworkID>` should be replaced by [`%UserProfile%`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)...

Comment: @Stephan yes they are one in the same.

Comment: Then, @aschipfl already gave the correct answer: use `%username%` or even better `%userprofile%`.

Comment: Error messages can be avoiding using `IF EXIST "%USERPROFILE%\OneDri..." (DEL "%USERPROFILE%\OneDri..")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating variables for the file names will make it more readable and maintainable. Also, the copy process can specify the destination filename, so a REN is not needed.

```
SET "OLDFILE=%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Desktop\CID FE v1.6.accdb"
SET "NETFILE=\\server\data\NFInventory\groups\CID\CID Database\CID FE v1.7 DO NOT USE -- FOR COPY ONLY.accdb"
SET "NEWFILE=%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Desktop\CID FE v1.7.accdb"

IF EXIST "%OLDFILE%" (DEL /F "%OLDFILE%")
XCOPY /Y /F "%NETFILE%" "%NEWFILE%"
```

Comment: This works and I like that you included if it exists or not too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Deke - Should the OLDFILE name have a `.accdb` extension?

Answer (score 1):

What you call the `<NetworkID>` is the user name as I see it, which can be easily referred to by the built-in [environment variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) `%UserName%`. To refer to the user profile directory `%SystemDrive%\Users\%UserName%` you can even use the variable `%UserProfile%`. So your code should finally look like this:

```cmd
del /F "C:\Users\<NetworkID>\OneDrive\Desktop\CID FE v1.6" 2> nul
xcopy /Y /F "\\server\data\NFInventory\groups\CID\CID Database\CID FE v1.7 DO NOT USE -- FOR COPY ONLY.accdb" "%UserProfile%\OneDrive\Desktop\"
rename "C:\Users\<NetworkID>\OneDrive\Desktop\CID FE v1.7 DO NOT USE -- FOR COPY ONLY.accdb" "CID FE v1.7.accdb"
```

*N. B.:*
In your `rename` command line the target file name was not quoted although it contains spaces.

Comment: This works just need to change the <networkID> with "%UserProfile%"  Thanks!!

Comment: No you'd change `C:\Users\<NetworkID>` to `%UserProfile%` or change `<NetworkID>` to `%UserName%`.